# Extract part of a regression type output

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, regression

Below, I was wondering how I could extract the last part of the output of `result` titled `Likelihood Ratio Test`?

```
library(weightr)

y <- dat.bangertdrowns2004$yi
v <- dat.bangertdrowns2004$vi

(result <- weightfunct(y, v))
# .
# .
# .
Likelihood Ratio Test:                     ## This part
X^2(df = 1) = 1.163544, p-val = 0.28073    ## This part
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to look at the function that produces the output. In this case it is `weightr:::print.weightfunct` and the relevant lines are

```
<snip>
        cat("\n")
        cat("Likelihood Ratio Test:")
        cat("\n")
        df <- length(x[[2]]$par) - length(x[[1]]$par)
        lrchisq <- 2 * (abs(x[[1]]$value - x[[2]]$value))
        pvalue <- 1 - pchisq(lrchisq, df)
        cat("X^2(df = ", df, ") = ", lrchisq, ", p-val = ", format.pval(pvalue), 
            sep = "")
</snip>
```

So you can grab the values with

```
x = result
df <- length(x[[2]]$par) - length(x[[1]]$par)
lrchisq <- 2 * (abs(x[[1]]$value - x[[2]]$value))
pvalue <- 1 - pchisq(lrchisq, df)

> lrchisq
#[1] 1.163544
> pvalue
#[1] 0.2807317
```

Answer (score 2):

The indicated output is computed in `print.weightfunct` so we can copy the print method and then add a trace to it which captures and outputs the required information into the one row data frame `.W` :

```
print.weightfunct <- weightr:::print.weightfunct
trace(print.weightfunct, exit = quote(.W <<- data.frame(df, lrchisq, pvalue)))
(result <- weightfunct(y, v))
## ...snip ## 
.W
##   df  lrchisq    pvalue
## 1  1 1.163544 0.2807317
```

Comment: That's very neat. And more general than my answer as can be used to grab all the many different stats that are calculated in the print call and  output

Comment: But I think this is a dangerous method (I upvoted it, though). I'm planning to use the solution inside a function and when tested it on three different sets of data, the function only outputted the result of the first dataset even when I inputted different datasets! I think the culprit is `<<-`.

Comment: It happens through the print function so maybe you forgot to print it.  To use it within a function and have the function capture .W you will need to initialize .W to any value (NULL will do) and then set the environment of the print method to the environment inside the function like this (after the code in the answer): `f <- function(x) {
.W <- NULL;
environment(print.weightfunct) <- environment();
print(x);
print(.W)
};
f(result)`

Answer (score 1):

An option is

```
out <- capture.output(result)
out[cumsum(grepl("Likelihood", out)) > 0]
#[1] "Likelihood Ratio Test:"                 
#[2] "X^2(df = 1) = 1.163544, p-val = 0.28073"
```